# Injecting dependencies into IWindsorInstaller implementations

Tags: c#, inversion-of-control, castle-windsor

I have a scenario where I would like to read configuration data for an inversion of control container (Castle Windsor) from a custom data store. This custom data store has a table-like structure that lists a set of (potentially bespoke) components that implement required interfaces in the system.

For example, the application requires an implementation of `IFoo`, but the actual assembly and type containing that implementation is defined in this custom data store.

I'd like to have an implementation of `IWindsorInstaller` that reads the data structure and registers the correct implementor of `IFoo`. However, to correctly access my custom data store I need access to a factory class (implementing a `IDataConnectionProvider` interface). This type is registered in the container, but I don't know if it is reasonable to do something like:

```
var container = new WindsorContainer();
container.Register(Component.For<IDataConnectionProvider>.
               ImplementedBy<DefaultDataConnectionProvider>.
               DependsOn(new { host, service });
container.Install(FromAssembly.This());
```

And then have a class in the assembly:

```
public class PluginInstaller : IWindsorInstaller
{
   public void Install(IWindsorContainer container, IConfigurationStore store)
   {
     var dataStoreConnection = container.Resolve<IDataConnectionProvider>();
     // read table, register other services    
   }
}
```

Is that the best way to do what I'm trying to do? Other suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, that is probably what I would do too. The `container` parameter within your plugin installer is there precisely for this reason.

You also can register `host` and `service` within the container and have it wire up your default data connection provider automatically, i.e. there's no need for `DependsOn`.

Answer (score 0):

In general this is not a good idea to resolve anything before installation process is finished.

Instead I would not register the `IDataConnectionProvider` in the container (unless some other components require that) but just pass it into your installer's constructor:

```
container.Install(
   new PluginInstaller(new DefaultDataConnectionProvider(){Host = host},
   FromAssembly.This()
);
```

Notice that the last call will try to instantiate the `PluginInstaller`  again, so the simplest way to avoid that is to make the class internal.